# Flutter build fails with a plugin that has androidX support for an application with androidX

Tags: flutter

When the release build for the plugin that has support for android, an error occurs

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      85,4s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve
the incompatibility.
Building plugin connectivity...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                   11,6s
√ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
Building plugin flutter_inappwebview...
The plugin flutter_inappwebview could not be built due to the issue above.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                            -
```

File gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Flutter version: 
`1.12.13+hotfix.5`
Platform: 
`android-29, build-tools 28.0.3`

Comment: the plugin you are using is not supporting androidx

Comment: but in the description of the plugin it says that it has been supporting the android since version older than 0.6.0, now the current version is 2.1.0.

Comment: Did you followed the proper steps from Flutter documentation to haveyour app to AndroidX ?

Comment: @Testeur Maniak I made a new installation completely from scratch using the command `flutter create --androidx {name}` and as a result, the entire config meets the requirements